# D3: How to select every thing under svg element

Tags: select, d3.js

I create an svg element under body. Subsequently I append more things to the svg.

```
svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 500)

svg.append("g")
// ... and many others more
```

How do I select everything under svg but svg itself? Like,

```
d3.select(all_under("svg"))
```

Comment: Why don't you use class and add it to the elements ( example: .attr('class','myClass')) that you want to select and then use selection by class like: d3.selectAll('.myClass')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d3.select('svg').selectAll('*')
```

or even better as [Lars Kotthoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff) purposed:

```
d3.selectAll("svg > *")
```

Comment: Or even `d3.selectAll("svg > *")`.